# Como obter um refresh token no Jasmin usando o processo Authorization Code Grant

Tags: api, oauth2

No último passo do processo de OAuth Authorization Code Grant quando se pede um `access_token` a partir do url `https://identity.primaverabss.com/connect/token` este não está a devolver o `refresh_token` como esperado segundo a documentação em https://developers.primaverabss.com/jasmin/?cat=recursos-2&subcat=referencias&pID=2324. Como é que é possível activar este token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ter a possibilidade de usar Refresh Tokens o client id da sua aplicação deverá ter configurações e acessos específicos. À data, estas configurações ainda não se encontram disponíveis na plataforma de registo de aplicações (Nitrogen) pelo que deverá submeter o pedido diretamente junto do produtor.